# MySQL update table based on results from another query

Tags: php, mysql

If I have table logs :

```
ID   Date     P_id     TYPE
-------------------------------
1   2016-9-1   11    adClick       
2   2016-9-1   22   adComplete
3   2016-9-1   11    adClick
4   2016-9-3   22    adClick        
5   2016-9-3   22    adClick        
6   2016-9-1   11    adClick        
7   2016-9-3   22   adComplete        
8   2016-9-1   11    adClick        
9   2016-9-3   11    adClick        
-------------------------------
```

and another table report having the same Date & P_id as follows :

```
ID   Date     P_id     clicks   
--------------------------------
1   2016-9-1   11      
2   2016-9-3   11      
3   2016-9-1   11        
4   2016-9-3   11      
5   2016-9-1   22      
6   2016-9-1   11           
5   2016-9-1   22           
---------------------------------
```

I need MySQL query to spread clicks in report table according to the key (Date & P_id) and if there is remainder, add one randomly untill finish remainder with the same keys selected :

```
clicks = 
         count of rows having (Date & P_id) in logs table 
        -------------------  Divistion (/) -------------------
    count of rows having (Date & P_id) in Report and Type is adClick
```

The count for each group by keys (Date & P_id) and event type is adClick in logs table is :

```
2016-9-1  11 --- count-->  4
2016-9-1  22 --- count-->  0

2016-9-3  11 --- count-->  1
2016-9-3  22 --- count-->  2
```

And count in report table :

```
2016-9-1  11 --- count-->  3
2016-9-1  22 --- count-->  2

2016-9-3  11 --- count-->  2
2016-9-3  22 --- count-->  0
```

So the table will be :

```
ID   Date     P_id      clicks   
--------------------------------
1   2016-9-1   11      4 / 3 = 1 and 1 as remainder
2   2016-9-3   11      1 / 2 = 0 and 1 as remainder 
3   2016-9-1   11      4 / 3 = 1 and 1 as remainder 
4   2016-9-3   11      1 / 2 = 0 and 1 as remainder 
5   2016-9-1   22      0 / 2 = 0
6   2016-9-1   11      4 / 3 = 1 and 1 as remainder
5   2016-9-1   22      0 / 2 = 0
---------------------------------
```

Sample to explain more , first row :

```
2016-9-1   11      4 / 3 

4 rows (2016-9-1   11) in logs  table with type=adClick by
3 row  (2016-9-1   11) in report table
```

I have done the part of saving the clicks without the remainder, so records with my query in report table are :

```
    ID   Date     P_id      clicks   
    --------------------------------
    1   2016-9-1   11         1
    2   2016-9-3   11         0
    3   2016-9-1   11         1 
    4   2016-9-3   11         0
    5   2016-9-1   22         0
    6   2016-9-1   11         1
    5   2016-9-1   22         0
    ---------------------------------
```

Now I want to spread the remainder - maybe randomly - to the report table so that the sum of the same keys stays the same :

```
    ID   Date     P_id      clicks   
    --------------------------------
    1   2016-9-1   11         1 + 1
    2   2016-9-3   11         0 + 1
    3   2016-9-1   11         1 
    4   2016-9-3   11         0
    5   2016-9-1   22         0
    6   2016-9-1   11         1
    5   2016-9-1   22         0
    ---------------------------------
```

so the sum of clicks for (2016-9-1   11) now is 4 for both tables.

Here is the query I am using to update before using the remainder :

```
UPDATE report AS r
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DATE(ctr_date) as report_date, report.placement_id, count(*) as cnt_report, cnt_event_type
        FROM report
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT DATE(ctr_date) as event_date, placement_id, SUM(event_type = 'adClick') as cnt_event_type
            FROM logs
            GROUP BY DATE(ctr_date),placement_id
        ) inner_report

        ON report.date = inner_report.event_date AND report.placement_id = inner_report.placement_id
        GROUP BY report.date, report.placement_id
    ) result_table

    ON r.date = result_table.report_date AND r.placement_id= result_table.placement_id
    SET r.clicks = COALESCE( (cnt_event_type - MOD(cnt_event_type,cnt_report))/cnt_report ,0);
```

I was thinking of using the same query but with limit (remainder) for same keys and use :

```
SET r.clicks = r.clicks + 1
```

Comment: It would seem to me that it might be easier and more maintainable either to do this with in your code or add a stored stored procedure to do this. Which way is best depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the remainders for the same keys in a temp table. And using that table went through the report table for the same key and incremented the previous value according the remainder value from the temp table.